# my wcf services only show directory listing and no wsdl

Tags: wcf, wsdl, mex

I have a few wcf services created a number of ways.

all of them only display the directory listing when i browse to them.

(I fixed the part about authentication)

Also I have very nice mex settings for all of them as well.

it seems to me that there should be a file in the service location to browse to?

its especially annoying that I can't display a wsdl file despite the mex settings.

Answer (score 1):

oops...

all i had to do was browse to one of the service files.

like... any file ending in .svc

well, dumb stuff happens